# Unity 2D - Null Reference upon script activation

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a problem i can't seem to fix.

I have an AIManager script. This has all the controls and how my enemy would move.
Then I have an EnemyBasic script. This represents the AI behaviour of this enemy. How often he will attack etc.

I tried using a tutorial about Raycasts, that can help me implement sight for my enemies. This worked and my enemy does spot me, tested with a public bool.

Now the problematic part. If I disable the EnemyBasic script my enemy stays in one place, which I want. After I enter his sight I want to activate the EnemyBasic script, so he can start attacking me. Unfortunately, with my code, this gives an error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Sight.Raycasting () (at Assets/Sight.cs:21)
Sight.Update () (at Assets/Sight.cs:13)

Here is my code:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sight : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform sightStart, sightEnd;
    public bool spotted = false;

    void Update () {
        Raycasting();
    }

     void Raycasting()
    {
        spotted = Physics2D.Linecast(sightStart.position, sightEnd.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"));

        if (spotted)
        {
           /*---> LINE OF ERROR */ gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyBasic>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas. I am new to unity, so there is a high chance its something stupid. 
Thank you!

Comment: Double-click on the error and post the line of code that is causing the error.

Comment: Done. I added an arrow.

Comment: Ok. 1.What is the name of GameObject the `Sight` script above is attached to? 2.What is the name of GameObject the `EnemyBasic` script is attached to?

Comment: Both of them are attached under a GameObject called Enemy1.

Comment: Either `gameObject` is `null` or `gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyBasic>()` is, but there's **nothing in the code you've shown** that gives us the information to give you a fix. Please post a [mcve] if you want help.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you. That was the error. I had my SIght under a Sight GameObject, under Enemy1. I moved the Sight script directly to Enemy1. Problem solved. You pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: `GetComponent<EnemyBasic>()` is null. `gameObject` cannot be null since it's a local reference to the object this script is attached to. When you use `gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyBasic>()`, you are tyring to get a script that is attached to this GameObject so `EnemyBasic` must be attached to the-same GameObject your `Sight` script is attached to. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Programmer suggested in the comments. Turns out my Sight script was not under the same GameObejct as the EnemyBasic script. Copied the script over and it works like a charm.